# Combine 3 select fields and validate as one in my User model in ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Ok I have 3 select boxes for selecting date of birth.

I have constants setup in my User model to provide months, years etc..

Anyway I can successfully validate these select boxes separately.

***What I want to do*** is combine the :day, :month and :year and store in :birthday and validate the whole date as one so I can return 1 error rather than 3 separate ones.

Also doing this will make it easier to store the validated date in my birthday field in my database.

**Part of my form**

```
    <td> <%= f.input :day, :required => false, :label => "Birthday: " , :prompt => "Day", :collection => User::DAYS  %></td>
 <td> <%= f.input :month, :label => false, :prompt => "Month", :collection => User::MONTHS %> </td> 
 <td> <%= f.input :year, :label => false, :prompt => "Year", :collection => User::YEAR_RANGE %> </td>
```

**Part of User model**

> MONTHS = ["January", 1], ["February",
>   2], ["March", 3], ["April", 4],
>   ["May", 5], ["June", 6], ["July", 7],
>   ["August", 8], ["September", 9],
>   ["October", 10], ["November", 11],
>   ["December", 12] # finish this DAYS =
>   1..31 # finish this START_YEAR = Time.now.year - 106 END_YEAR =
>   Time.now.year  YEAR_RANGE =
>   START_YEAR..END_YEAR
>
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>        attr_accessor :day, :month, :year
>
> validates_presence_of :day, :message
>   => 'What day in a month was you born?'
>   validates_presence_of :month, :message
>   => 'What month was you born?'
>   validates_presence_of :year, :message
>   => 'What is your year of birth?'
>
> end

Comment: Do you have to store year/month/day separately? If not, why aren't you using a date or datetime field?

Comment: No I have to store in one column in my database. I was using date_select field and it all stored fine in the database but I spent 4-5 days trying to validate it but it just wouldn't work so I gave up.. I tried plugins, examples on here and posted 2 questions on here but couldn't get the help. So in the end I decided to create 3 separate select fields. If I had to store the year/month/day separately I would be fine right now but I think it's better for me to store date as yyyy-mm-dd in 1 db column.

Comment: On a conventional date column what are you trying to validate: presence, uniqueness, within a range, etc? In other words, do they just need to make sure a date is selected or does it have to be something earlier than a specific time, et al?

Comment: Firstly I want to make sure they have selected something. So nil/blank values aren't permitted. Then maybe after that I'll want to check the date is valid.

Comment: Valid in what way? Do they have to be of a certain age?

Comment: Date valid as in a real date. So 31 of feb not allowed for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the column to datetime (date never seems to work for me).

```
  t.datetime :birthday
```

Then use a [date_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) in your view.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :birthday %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :birthday, :include_blank => true, :start_year => Time.now.year - 70 %>
  </div>
```

Then in your model validate birthday presence.

```
  validates_presence_of :birthday
```

If you need to make sure the birthday is older than a certain age, write a custom validation.

```
  validate :of_certain_age

private

  def of_certain_age
    if self.birthday
      errors.add(:base, 'You need to be at least 18.') if self.birthday > 18.years.ago
    end
  end
```

Comment: Tried exactly this and it doesn't work. Quite fed up and can't find the cause. No matter what I do errors will not show for date field.

Comment: It doesn't work to do what? I pasted all that from a demo app I made. It doesn't allow a record to be created without a birthday, and it doesn't allow the birthday to be less than 18 years from the current day.

Comment: I basically want the error to show beside the birthday field. Everything else I use "validates_presence_of" on shows he appropriate error beside the associated field. With the date field it never shows. I even have a select gender field select box and the error for that shows also.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing your point completely you just need a custom validation.
This is an example of how to do it.

----- begin model code ------

```
validate :check_date_validity

def check_date_validity 

  date_submitted = Date.strptime("#{self.year}/#{self.month}/#{self.day}" , "%Y/%m/%d")
  errors.add(:birthday, "does not look right") if date_submitted < Date.today  #for example

end
```

----- begin view code ------

```
<%= f.select( :day, User::DAYS ) %>

<%= f.select( :month, User::MONTHS ) %>

<%= f.select( :year, User::YEAR_RANGE ) %>
```

See the [rails guides documentation for custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods) for more info.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Is it grabbing the values of :day, :month and :year? Because what I need it to do is check to see if there are any values and if not validation fails and error shows. So all 3 select boxes have to be selected.

Comment: self.year, self.month and self.day refer to the values input via the selects in the form.